# Android delete folders after change of ad network

Tags: android, memory, directory, ads

To display ads, files are downloaded by Ad SDKs and stored in the app's private directory:

```
data/data/com.example.myapp/cache
data/data/com.example.myapp/files
data/data/com.example.myapp/databases
```

Some ad SDKs manage to download and store many megabytes of images.
After a change of ad network those files are no longer used and should probably be deleted, to free up memory.
Which folders are safe to delete?

(For example, Google Analytics writes to the `/databases` folder, so it shouldn't be deleted completely).

If the app doesn't have `write_external_storage`permission, can ad SDKs write to other folders than mentioned above?

Answer (score 1):

It is not good to delete any of the directories you suggested.You do not need permissions to create directory in the internal storage.
You can create a directory write inside your application package directory like this

```
String appDir = getApplicationInfo().dataDir;
String pathToNewDirectory = appDir+"/test";
boolean dirCreated = new File(pathToNewDirectory).mkdir();
```